# What are the largest Technic-compatible tires on the market?

Tags: technic, size, wheel

I am looking for the largest LEGO wheels with tires available to build a nice-sized RC LEGO car.

Of course I will start with the simplest prototype, but I would like to achieve a design which will embed an automatic gear box and quite a large propulsion system. So the size of the wheels will be important.

---

**Edit**: The "Wheel 81.6x15" 2903 @Pubby8 found seem to be the biggest. But they are thin... Are there any other larger ones? Even 3rd party would be good.

**Edit**: @Joubarc & @Pubby8 found the biggest wheels but without tires I am still looking for 3rd party solutions before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The largest wheels I know are these (I measured 110x63 mm, including tyres), but they are quite rare (only available in one single set):

Weels: [22969 "Wheel Technic Racing"](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/22969)
Tyres: [32298 "Tyre Power Puller"](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/32298)

The wheels itself are not that big, but if you include the tyres, they are really huge:

[image: 4x4 offroader]

They would probably work really well for an RC car.

Comment: The largest wheels are on the 8466

Answer (score 10):

The largest wheels I've seen are "Wheel 81.6x15" 2903

[image]

To show scale:

[image]

There are larger ones on the Hailfire Droid but these probably aren't good for your needs:

[image]

Comment: Peeron lists them as "Wheel 81.6x15" 2903 (http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/2903) and "Tyre 81.6x15 Motorcycle" 2902 (http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/2902)

Comment: Part 2903 is also more common, It exists in 23 sets, including the RCX series which was fairly popular at the time it was released.

Answer (score 10):

An alternative is the [94.8x44 balloon tires](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/54120). While they are not as big as the ones elusive suggested, I imagine they are easier to get as they have been in some recent sets.

Comparison:
[image: Wheel size comparison]

- Left: 81.6x15
- Middle: 94.8x44 balloon
- Right: 81.6x38 balloon

Answer (score 7):

Answer to this question is no longer entirely accurate, the power puller wheel
https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32298
[image]
has been superseded in diameter by the tractor wheel
https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=23798
[image]

by an entire mm :) (resp. 106-107 mm)

Comment: To me the 32298 "Tyre Power Puller" seems more suitable for an RC car though, with the high width and nice curvature. Should have better offroad capabilities and more grip when doing tight turns, despite the 23798 "Tractor" having a deeper profile.

Comment: Those power puller wheels are very heavy & not that good for rc applications as they bog down the motor & you loose a lot of power. They are made from a different material than the new tires… But they are really cool!! I’ve used them with a two different transmission and nothing can get past the weight to make them effect. These are the smaller ones but they’re very effective for rc use. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjA0I.jpg

Answer (score 6):

There is also the [Technic Gear Mobile Devastator Wheel](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/59521), but it's not really suited if you want a realistic car. If you want to build a funny-looking vehicle, however... You could even build a complete vehicle which fits completely inside the radius of two such wheels, so that it can turn on itself when you reverse the polarity. Again, not a car, but super funny.

[image: 59521 - Technic Gear Mobile Devastator Wheel]

Answer (score 4):

I personally have the Lego Group 62.4 x 20 S tires which came with the Lego Creator 7291 2-in-1 Motorcycle kit.[image]

Comment: While not as big as the ones in the accepted answer, these may be more available due to the larger number of sets they appeared in.

Answer (score 4):

The largest (by diameter) tyre so far is [Tire 139mm D. x 37mm Motorcycle Racing Tread](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=71722)

[image]

with [Tire 132.6mm D. x 27mm Motorcycle Racing Tread Narrow](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=71721) coming next.

[image]

Both are included in following sets:

- [BMW M 1000 RR (42130)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42130-1)
- [Yamaha MT-10 SP (42159)](https://brickset.com/sets/42159-1)

Answer (score 1):

The new `6141782: TYRE TRACTOR DIA. 107X44` is now the largest ever wheel available and made by LEGO.

https://brickset.com/parts/6141782

[image]

Comment: This piece has already mentioned in one of the prior answers.

Answer (score 0):

Well if your doing an RC car you can go what I call "lazy fashion" and get the 47349c05 which were for that and pretty huge.

But the 2902's and 6596's work great for me as well.

But my personal favorite is 92912. Its a bit smaller then 32298 but much meaner if you ask me.

I buy most of my tires from ItsaGoodyear. Its been a while sense I last needing anything though.

Another tire you might want to try is "3740" I never used it myself but if its anything like its smaller counter part 4267. It might work great :D

Also 11957 might be a good one to look into.

Answer (score -1):

How about the old school tyres of the #8860 chassis:
http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/8860-1

Cheers,

Dennis

Comment: They are fairly large, but have sadly been surpassed by others. The 94.8x44 balloon (the middle one in Sebastian Wahl's answer) beats the 24x43 one in that set :(