# Can I get LEGO compatible wheels 3cm in diameter or bigger?

Tags: vehicle

I want to make a formula one car at least 30 cm in length out of standard LEGO parts. None of the LEGO wheels I have are big enough for this scale. Where can I get some big wheels that would look ok? The big tires [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/235/what-are-the-largest-technic-compatible-wheels-on-the-market) are too big. I looked on [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com), but just got confused.

Comment: 30mm diameter wheels seems small for a 30cm car, to be honest

Comment: You are probably right. I may have to scale it down a bit to fit the wheels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to have a look at some official LEGO sets of that scal to check what LEGO has been using.

For example, [2556-1 — SHELL Promotional Set F1 Ferrari](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/2556-1) seems to be about that length and uses 49mm diameter [wheels](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/6595) and [tires](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/6594).

A similar wheel can be found in more recent sets, such as [8041 — Race Truck](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/8041-1), which may be [cheaper](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?itemID=65845).

You can also look in the specific section for [wheels](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?v=1&pg=2&catString=43&catType=P) on BrickLink for other sizes.

Comment: Ok, thanks. There are a some of those on bricklink, but rather pricey. Do they fit a standard technics axle?

Answer (score 5):

`Wheel 30.4 x 14 VR` with the tire is ~3 cm (the 30.4 and 14 is mm). It also looks good for sports cars.

[image: Wheel 30.4 x 14 VR]

Comment: Worth noting that the units are millimeters in the descriptions, right?

Comment: Thanks. Do they fit a standard technics axle?