# What is the biggest LEGO-compatible one piece wheel?

Tags: wheel

I am wondering what the biggest LEGO one piece wheel is? (the inside part and the rubber part counts as one piece in my world)

Comment: See also the related question: [What are the largest Technic-compatible tires on the market?](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/235/56) - although that is specifically asking for tires.

Comment: Am I the only one that noticed they never specified Lego wheel?  I think some absurd answers are in order. ;)

Comment: I noticed. I also noticed your answer. ;)

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid, Thank you for removing my post from this thread. I agree it was not on topic. I am new here and will not do it again. Also I apologize for using a comment to respond but I cannot figure out how to send a message to another user. I am really new.

Comment: Well, got a few laughs out of it before the edit.  Harmless fun, apologizes for any feathers ruffled.

Comment: @Dan1138 JohnnyB no problem either of you - while a bit of fun is always appreciated, if it can be in the context of an on-topic answer that would be great. Otherwise we'll just end up with joke answers everywhere ;)

Answer (score 5):

Pretty sure it's [Hailfire Droid Wheel](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=x784).

Comment: Confirmed, though it is missing a center hub and is thus difficult to use. The next in size that does have one is 59521 http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=59521