# Looking for a big set of tires and rims for my monster truck - really beefy tires

Tags: technic, compatibility, wheel

I'm looking for big beefy tires and rims for my large Technic monster truck. I also need something for off-roading.

Comment: How large is "large" here?

Comment: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/235/what-are-the-largest-technic-compatible-tires-on-the-market

Comment: Hi Hunter Mentch, and welcome to Bricks! As RSchulz points out we do already have a fairly comprehensive answer to "What large tires are/have been available" - are you able to supply any more details about your planned build that would help differentiate your question (i.e. what scale are you aiming for, etc.)?

Comment: Im working on a monster truck /rock crawler

Answer (score 6):

You may want to check Sariel's [Wheels chart](http://wheels.sariel.pl). This table contains all essential details like dimensions of the wheel and rim as well as weight and how rare they are.